# Bootstrap form not collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms

Attempting to use Bootstrap collapse in a form and it is non-responsive. Copy & pasted directly from the Bootstrap website but still does not work. Please help!

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" data-target="firstname" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
   Test
 </a>
<form>
  <div class="form-row mb-1 collapse" id="firstname">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal first name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Legal last name">
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: there is no collapseExample id in your case

Comment: you havent used it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `id = "collapseExample"`or `data-target="#collapseExample"` from the element that you want to toggle
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: How so? The element that I want to trigger the collapse (btn) is indicated with data-target and the element that I want to toggle (form-row) is indicated with id. This is exactly how Bootstrap lays out the code in the link that you supplied.

Comment: cause the `id` is the most important, i guess the `collapse` css classes are used by bootstrap for styling but if you check also another example https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h you can see that if you remove `class="collapse"` it will work. so pls add `data-target="#demo"` and `id="demo"` and then add also `data-toggle="collapse"` with the `class='collapse'` - it is very simple what you are trying to achieve. i would suggest studying more and experimenting further